# Wirelessly controlling song playing on iPod from iTunes

Tags: itunes, remote, ipod-touch

Using the "Remote" app from apple I can control the song that is being played on my computer from my iPod touch.

I was hoping that there would be some similar functionality controlling what song is playing on my iPod Touch.

My stereo is across the room from my computer and I often plug in my iPod to the stereo when I am working on my computer across the room.  Without jail-breaking my phone, can I control the track that is playing in on my iPod?

Answer (score 2):

Use Bowtie [App](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=352276968&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6) + [Client](http://bowtieapp.com/)